# In ES6, how do you get the name of the generator function inside the generator?

Tags: generator, v8, ecmascript-harmony

Using normal ECMAScript you can do something like,

```
function f () { console.log(this.constructor.name); }
new f() // outputs `f`
```

However, a slight modification,

```
function* f () { console.log(this.constructor.name); }
var g = new f();
g.next() // outputs `GeneratorFunctionPrototype`
```

Is there anyway to get the generator's name (`f`)?

Comment: I don't think the function has to have a name, although one might argue the name (inside) is "f". Although not a strong argument, `Function.prototype.name` is non-standard and `constructor.name` is really just an artifact of the new object - not the function.

Comment: Do you have to use `this`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the property `callee` of the `arguments` object. **However** note that `callee`was removed from the ES5 strict mode (no idea about ES6 unfortunately).

So you'd get something like:

```
function* f () {console.log(arguments.callee.name);}
var g = new f();
g.next() // outputs `f`
```